# Android, форматирование даты

Tags: java, android, дата, время, format

У меня выводит дату вот так:

```
Tue Dec 11 17:00:00 EST 2012
```

А м не нужно, что бы её выводило вот так:

```
11.12.2012 17:00
```

Как правильно это сделать ?

**UPDATE**

Код:

```
viewHolder.roomCreateDate.setText(String.valueOf(room.getCreationDate()));
```

> room.getCreationDate() - возвращает Date.

С кодом ничего сложного, просто ставим дату, но мне нужно изменить формат даты.

Comment: где код, который нужно изменить, чтобы дату выводило так, как вам надо?

Comment: А зачем код? Здесь разве не с форматами работать нужно ? Но все равно сейчас добавлю ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для форматирования даты-времени можно использовать [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
В общем случае так:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String formatted = ftm.format(someDate);
```